# Are there infinitely many primes of primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Primes of primes are prime numbers where each digit is also prime. I have written a computer program to generate such primes from [the first 2 billion primes](http://www.primos.mat.br/2T_en.html)! So far, the program has given me $75,249$ primes of primes (and counting). Is it known whether there are infinitely many such primes?

Comment: According to http://fs.unm.edu/SYLSMITH.HTM this is an open conjecture.

Comment: This is sequence A019546 in the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A019546) and the references there may be helpful. The largest known such prime apparently has $82000$ digits.

Comment: Considering the number of possibilities for a given number of digits , there are almost surely infinite many such prime numbers (in fact, there should even be infinite many primes consisting only of $3$'s and $2$'s). But this has not been proven.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My guess is that someone found a larger such (probable) prime not listed in OEIS.

Comment: A tip for the brute force search. Instead of checking the primes whether they have all digits being prime enumerate all numbers containing only the digits $2,3,5,7$ with some number of digits and check them for primality. This will be much faster.

Comment: @Peter My program does not check whether all digits are prime. Well, at least not necessarily. What the program does is, if it encounters the first instance of a composite digit, it terminates and starts checking the prime number on the next line.

Comment: @Peter Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. I have carried out some tests and your method sure is faster.